# How do I add a Header row in WPF in a ListView of Grid with ColumnDefintions?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, header

I am using a ViewModel to bind the data to the view in every textblock. I shortened the code to the most important parts.

Now, I wanna add a Header row into this structure. So every Column defined below in Grid.RowDefinitions shoudl have a constant header text. Any idea how I can realise this?

```
    <Grid>
    <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentView}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:ViewModel">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1">
                    <Expander ToolTip="Expand" ExpandDirection="Down" Foreground="Black">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Text="{Binding Model.Number, StringFormat='#{0}', Mode=OneWay}" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Width="50">
                                    <Hyperlink />
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Width="100" />
                                <Button Grid.Column="5" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <GroupBox Header="Description" FontWeight="Bold">
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Description, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
                        </GroupBox>
                    </Expander>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

OK, you guys are a good help :) i changed the structure to the code below and the headers are working fine!

But in my original code, there is this expander. Everywhere in the row, i could click to expand the description. The expander now won't work with the new design. Any ideas?
Basically i want something like this:

```
<ListView Name="test2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
              <Expander>
              <Expander ToolTip="Expand" ExpandDirection="Down" Foreground="Black">
                <Expander.Header>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Column1">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"> </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Column2">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
                </Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Here goes the Description" />
                <Expander>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9YU2.png) (please ignore my paint skills)

Comment: Try using GridView inside ListVIew

Comment: Hmm some more information would be nice. Where can I use the GridView exactly? I am new to WPF developement and currently this is mostly try and error for me.

Comment: please go through the link for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-display-listview-contents-by-using-a-gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give every column a header but im not sure if this is what your intentions are:

```
<ListView x:Name="test" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentView}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:ViewModel">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1">
                        <Expander ToolTip="Expand" ExpandDirection="Down" Foreground="Black">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0">Column 1</Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1">Column 2</Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2">Column 3</Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3">Column 4</Label>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Text="{Binding Model.Number, StringFormat='#{0}', Mode=OneWay}" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
                                    <Image Grid.Column="1" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Width="50">
                            <Hyperlink />
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Width="100" />
                                    <Button Grid.Column="5" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Expander.Header>
                        </Expander>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

a better structure should look more like this (example you should modify it to satisfy you own needs):

```
 <ListView Name="test2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Column1">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Column2">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I think that i now understand what you're trying to achive

I tested this solution and it works fine, please try this with your own data:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key='key' Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyData}}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="@Catalog" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource='{Binding Source={StaticResource key}}' BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True"
                                          BorderBrush="Gray"
                                          BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <DockPanel>
                                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Item}"/>
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"
                    Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Titel"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding This}"
                    Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Should}"
                    Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Something"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Work}"
                    Width="100" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How it looks:

[image]

Comment: The only thing missing now is "<DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:ViewModel">". The Binding should bind to Text="{Binding Model.Title}". Does this work somehow?

Comment: Yes that should work. If not edit your question and show us what changes you made and what problem you're facing.

Comment: I tried it and now have a questiob: What is MyData supposed to be? My viewModel? It doesn't work if i use it there... And I never used "{Binding Path=Name}" before. What is this Path? I added an image of how the solution should look like. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I used Xaml generated data to test this solution, you just need to bind your collection to the ItemSource. You don't need to use Path, you can just bind your property: "{Binding Name}" is enough. I looked at your image and you can definitely achieve this with the XAML given above you just need to modify it to fit your own needs. I can't give you a fully functional code because i don't know what's in your viewmodel and how you collect your data.

Comment: First of all, thank you for all your detailed answers. Sadly I didn't manage to unfortunately I did not get this change executable... but I'm really close. I asked another question because this one here is solved. And I provided more information. Maybe you can give it another try... Thanks! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252768/how-can-i-group-gridviewcolumns-in-wpf-so-the-expander-fills-the-whole-width