# How can I group GridViewColumns in WPF, so the expander fills the whole width

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm, expander

I am new to WPF and try to do the following:

I have a ListView with a ItemsSource using a ViewModel.
Inside, there is a GridView with Columns. Each Column represents a Preoperty of the View Model. But the Description is optional and can be rather long. So I want to use a Expander. My Problem is, that I can only manage the expander to be as big as the Name-Column. But I want the expander to be as big as the whole row.
Here are 2 Images to clarify what I want.

My current State:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNA4v.png

What I want to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmFq1.png

I tried "grouping the GridView" but without success... See here
http://technico.qnownow.com/grouping-gridview-wpf/

Here's my Code

```
<Window ...>
<Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid>            
        <ListView Grid.RowSpan="4" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyView}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <!-- New GridView -->
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <!--Number-->
                    <GridViewColumn Header="#">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:MyViewModel">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Number, StringFormat='#{0}', Mode=OneWay}"
                                               Width="20" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <!--ErrorLevel-->
                    <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="45">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:MyViewModel">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Model.ErrorLevel, Converter={StaticResource ErrorLevelToImageConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                           ToolTip="{Binding Model.ErrorLevel, Mode=OneWay}" Width="20" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <!--ID-->
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:MyViewModel">
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                                        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Model.Hyperlink, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                   Command="{Binding HyperlinkCommand}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Id, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        </Hyperlink>
                                    </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <!--Name-->
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="500" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:MyViewModel">
                                <Expander ToolTip="Expand" ExpandDirection="Down" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                               TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <GroupBox Header="Description" FontWeight="Bold" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Description, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                       FontWeight="Normal" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
                                    </GroupBox>
                                </Expander>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <!-- Module-->
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Module" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:MyViewModel">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Module, Mode=OneWay}"
                                               TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Width="100" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Once again, i am new to WPF, MVVM, DataBinding and all this. So please try to make your answer as detailed as possible. I tried many things, but they didn't work out.

Comment: Do you want to sort the entries (eg. sort by ID)  with the `DataGrid` or is it not necessary?

Comment: Hmm no, I think they do not need to be in a specific order. I currently do not use a DataGrid. Could this help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the following `GridViewColumn` at the left side (top in XAML) to your `GridView`

```
<GridViewColumn Header="" Width="30">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:MyViewModel">
            <Expander Margin="-5,2,-5000,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsPresenter}}}">
                <GroupBox Header="Description" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Description}" FontWeight="Normal" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </GroupBox>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

This is `GridViewColumn`contains an empty `Header` which simply shows the `Expander`-Arrow in the `GridViewRow`s.

The `Expander` itself is left aligned and has a huge negative `Margin` on the right side, so it can draw its content outside of the right boundary. The width is set to the `ActualWidth` of the `ItemsPresenter` of your `GridView`. With this `Width` you can limit the content to the current visible `Width` of the `GridView` (Or you can set it to an absolute value like 500).

And finally a preview of this `Column`
[image]

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you for your work and your detailed answer. :-) EDIT: Looks like I am not allowed to thank you via comment... So I have to add a question. Is it possible to click the whole line to expand the description? right now, only a click on the expander image works. Would be a nice-to-have feature for me ;-)

Comment: I think a gratitude is never misplaced :) You could use the click-event of the `GridViewRow` to execute a `StoryBoard` which expands the `Expander`. I suggest you take a look at the MSDN how to animate a Property -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-a-property-by-using-a-storyboard

Answer (score 1):

OK, the fact that the expander is not stretchable is because of the non stretchable parent control. You have a column 'Name' in your gridview with a fixed width and a expander added as a child. As far as i know the child control cannot extend beyond the parent control if this is not truth im sure someone will correct this. I don't know what the best way is to achieve your goal but to give you some inspiration i made a small example.

So, to give you a example if how this could work:

Edit: You can just set negative margins on your expander like so:

```
<Expander ToolTip="Expand" ExpandDirection="Down" Margin="-100,0,-300,0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

Thanks to @LittleBit for this tip.

```
<ListView x:Name="lsttest" ItemsSource="{Binding persons}">
        <ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <ListView>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="#1" Width="50">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           Width="20" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Test 2" Width="50">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           Width="20" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <Expander ToolTip="Expand" ExpandDirection="Down" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                           TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <GroupBox Header="Description" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=lsttest}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   FontWeight="Normal" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
                    </GroupBox>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: A small Hint: Negative Margins sometimes allow a Child to render/draw outside its Boundaries.

Comment: Very good, i didn't know that this was possible with a fixed width on a parent control. But i tested it and it works. Thx @LittleBit for the tip.